# Segmentation fault when reading the arguments in the main function

Tags: c, command, argv

The user is supposed to pass some arguments when running the program, which have to have the following structure:
hanoiplus -d  -f  -o 
They can write them in different order and they don't even have to write all of them. For example:
hanoiplus -f hello -d 3
But it will only work if there is the word *hanoiplus* at the beggining.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HPLUS "hanoiplus"
#define DCMD "-d"
#define FCMD "-f"
#define OCMD "-o"

int main(int narg, char**cmd) {

if(strstr(HPLUS,cmd[1])){

for(int i=2; i <= narg; i++){

    if(strstr(DCMD,cmd[i]) && i<narg){ /*EXECUTE -d COMMAND IF SPECIFIED*/

        i++; //Increase i by 1 to go to the next command           
        printf("INPUT: %s %s",cmd[i-1],cmd[i]); //Change the number of disks to cmd[i]

    }else if(strstr(FCMD,cmd[i]) && i<narg){ /*EXECUTE -f COMMAND IF SPECIFIED*/

        i++;         
        printf("INPUT: %s %s",cmd[i-1],cmd[i]);
        create_file(cmd[i]);//Call the function that creates an external file

    }else if(strstr(OCMD,cmd[i]) && i<narg){ /*EXECUTE -o COMMAND IF SPECIFIED*/

        i++;         
        printf("INPUT: %s %s",cmd[i-1],cmd[i]);
        create_object(cmd[i]);//Call the function that calls the writing operation

    }
}
return 1; //The command(s) is/are valid.
}else{
return 0; //The command is not valid.
}
}
```

All the commands are saved as elements of char **cmd.
First of all, the program checks if the second command is "hanoiplus" -since the first command is always a path that I'm not interested in- and then it executes a for loop that iterates over **cmd as many times as elements **cmd has.
In each iteration, the program checks what command has been entered and it calls the function that carries out what the command represents.
The program also prints the input, so I can check if the arguments are being passed correctly.

Though the first iteration of the loop goes well, the second time the program crashes and it shows a segmentation fault.

Does anyone have any idea of what it is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Not the cause of your segfault, but: Your use of `strstr` makes no sense.  You want to be checking argument strings for equality.  Use things like `if(strcmp(DCMD, cmd[i] == 0)`.

Comment: Not the cause of your segfault, but: Your code will be infinitely easier for everyone else in the world to read, and help you debug, if you use standard names for the command-line arguments to `main`.  Please replace `narg` with `argc`, and `cmd` with `argv`.

Comment: The cause of your segfault is probably that you're running past the end of the argument array.  Arrays in C are 0-based.  Your loop over the arguments should start at 1 and end before the count: `for(int i=1; i < narg; i++)`.  When you make sure there's room for the option flag *and* the following argument, you need a +1 or a -1: `if(strcmp(DCMD,cmd[i]) == 0 && i+1<narg)`.

Comment: Not the cause of your segfault, but: insisting that the "first word" be "hanoiplus" is silly, unnecessary, and probably wrong.  But if you really did want to check that, you'd compare `argv[0]`, not `argv[1]`.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. The problem was that I had to write i < narg and not i<= narg, and hence that i+1<narg, just as you've just said. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

these expressions cause your program to access an no-existing argument `cmd[narg]`.

```
if(strstr(DCMD,cmd[i]) && i<narg)
```

So, `strstr` might crash because of it.  you need to swap the terms in the expression to avoid the issue:

```
if(i < narg && strstr(DCMD,cmd[i]))
```

or use `i < narg` in the loop.

Comment: He's got `i<narg` not to (try to) protect `strstr` from crashing, but to prevent the following `printf` from crashing.  What's supposed to printf `strstr` from crashing is the `(i=2; i <= narg; i++)` loop, but that's wrong, too.

Comment: @SteveSummit yes, but this was OP's mistake which would cause the crash. Swapping terms will prevent from crashing.

Comment: The OP had *many* mistakes.  Swapping the terms in the expression is a band-aid which doesn't really fix anything.  Changing the loop expression to `i < narg`, as you suggested at the end, is better, but what happens if you're at the very end of the arguments, you execute `i++` after one of the conditions succeeds, and call `printf("INPUT: %s %s",cmd[i-1],cmd[i])`?